# How to add data from XML feed to mysql DB

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, feed

I'm getting a deals feed and want to process it so I can add it my DB. Here is the format it is coming in:

```
<deals>
 <item>
  <couponid>int</couponid>
  <merchantid>int</merchantid>
  <merchantname>string</merchantname>
  <network>string</network>
  <label>string</label>
  <restrictions>string</restrictions>
  <couponcode>string</couponcode>
  <link>string</link>
  <directlink>string</directlink>
  <startdate>YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM TMZ</startdate>
  <enddate>YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM TMZ</enddate>
  <image>string</image>
  <dealtypes>
   <type>string</type>
  </dealtypes>
  <categories>
   <category>string</category>
  </categories>
  <status>status</status>
  <lastupdated>YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM TMZ</lastupdated>
  <errorreporturl>string</errorreporturl>
  <changeaudit>string</changeaudit>
  <price>string</price>
  <listprice>string</listprice>
  <discount>string</discount>
  <percent>string</percent>
  <local>
     <city>string</city>
     <state>string</state>
     <zipcode>string</zipcode>
     <address>string</address>
     <businessname>string</businessname>
     <businessurl>string</businessurl>
     <title2>string</title2>
     <expirationdate>string</expirationdate>
     <minpurchase>int</minpurchase>
     <maxpurchase>int</maxpurchase>
     <limitedqty>bool</limitedqty>
     <region>string</region>
  </local>
 </item>
</deals>
```

I can process most of the items using:

```
'couponid' => $node->getElementsByTagName('couponid')->item(0)->nodeValue
```

However, how do I process the items within the "local" node. Not all items in the feed have this "local" node. How would I process it? Would this work:

```
$localData = $node->getElementsByTagName('local')->item(0);
if $localData {
'city' => $node->getElementsByTagName('local')->item(city)->nodeValue;
'state' => $node->getElementsByTagName('local')->item(state)->nodeValue;
etc..
}
```

Comment: You said "Would this work", does it work?
Anyway maybe `$node->getElementsByTagName('local')->getElementsByTagName('city')->nodeValue` would work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`DOMNodeList`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), `DOMNodeList::item` will return

> The node at the indexth position in the DOMNodeList, or NULL if that
>   is not a valid index.

So, no, you can't do `$node->getElementsByTagName('local')->item(city)`.

When you do this `$localData = $node->getElementsByTagName('local')->item(0);` your `$localData` variable is set to a `DOMNode` object, whose children you can then access like any other `DOMNode` object's children.

**However**:

If you're simply reading XML and not writing/appending, PHP's SimpleXML is much simpler to use (hence the name) than DOM and I'd recommend it in your case:

```
$deals = new SimpleXMLElement($my_xml);

$city  = $deals->item->local->city[0];
$state = (string) $deals->item->local->state;

echo "city:  $city\n";
echo "state: $state\n";
```

Note that the method using the `(string)` cast yields the same result as simply referencing the `[0]` key of the element.

Comment: The original feed parsing script was provided by the feed owner. Not sure why they didn't use SimpleXML. The new script I'm writing is based on the code you gave me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do the following:

-> Get the xml file :

```
$myXMLString = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
$doc->loadXML($myXMLString);
$deals = $doc->getElementsByTagName("item");

foreach($deals as $item){
   functionDeals($item);
}
```

Then in function "functionDeals" extract the sub element the same way.
Otherwise the esiest way is to use Hibernate (Java): follow this link http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/mapping/

Hope this help